# Does the Radare Debugger support STABS?

Tags: radare2, debuggers, debugging-symbols

From the [wiki on Stabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabs)

> stabs (sometimes written STABS) is a debugging data format for storing information about computer programs for use by symbolic and source-level debuggers.

Does Radare support this?

Answer (score 1):

radare2 is not a source level debugger, thus there is no support for STABS. That said, you can always use `gdb` as a backend for radare2 either by connecting radare2 to a running `gdb` session or [by using the `gdbserver`](https://radare.gitbooks.io/radare2book/debugger/remote_gdb.html).

> radare2 allows remote debugging over the gdb remote protocol. So you
>   can run a gdbserver and connect to it with radare2 for remote
>   debugging. The syntax for connecting is:

```
$ r2 -d gdb://<host>:<port>
```